# debug issue how i can solve <terminated, exit value: 0>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\javaw.exe (Mar 4, 2020, 12:02:48 PM)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

[image]

I have placed a breakpoint, but when I run the code in debug mode, it keeps skipping the breakpoints and I don't see any variables:
[image]

I'm new to this can someone help me out here, thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide more information on what you did and which code you were running? It's quite difficult from your description to reproduce what happened.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, my program runs to the end without stopping at the breakpoint. As you see on the screenshot i have put a breakpoint on line 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **somewhere a so-called trigger point that have to be hit first to enable the breakpoint** in line 11.

Trigger points are decorated with a `T` and regular breakpoints are, if there are trigger points, decorated with a crossed-out `T` (like the breakpoint in line 11). In your case, with the trigger point not be hit the regular breakpoint will not become active and your program runs to the end without stopping at a breakpoint (`terminated` means *finished* and `exit value: 0` means *successfully*).

To disable, delete or convert the trigger point(s):

1. Go to the ***Breakpoints*** view
2. Do one of the following with all trigger points (those decorated with a `T`):

   - **Uncheck** them to disable them
   - **Select them and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>** to delete them
   - Select them one after the other and **uncheck the *Trigger Point* checkbox** to convert them into regular breakpoints

Comment: thank you so much for the comment, it's been unchecked "Trigger Point", but still program runs to the end without stopping at the breakpoint.

Comment: Yes, your are right. The breakpoint in line 11 is not a trigger point but somewhere else is a trigger point that is never be hit, so the breakpoint in line 11 will never become active. See my edited answer.

Comment: The issue is solved with your help, thanks again appreciated! :)